# If I see a process running using ps, how can I find the executable?

Tags: process, executable, ps

If I can see a process running using `ps -e`, how can I find the file which launched it?

Comment: What OS is this? Linux, BSD, Solaris...

Comment: linux ... but cross-unix solutions welcome.

Answer (score 21):

On Linux: if you know the PID, you can cat the cmdline file for that file.
E.g.:

```
cat /proc/PID/cmdline
```

This will probably fail if the binary was moved after the program was started.

And of course:

```
lsof -n | grep PID | grep ' txt '
```

and:

```
ls -la /proc/PID/exe
```

which is a symbolic link to the executable.

Comment: Note that `/proc/PID/cmdline` doesn't have a newline character, so you'll probably want to do something like `cat /proc/PID/cmdline ; echo ''`.

Comment: Actually, it has NUL characters separating the arguments, so you might want something even more elaborate like `tr '\0' ' ' < /proc/PID/cmdline ; echo ''`

Answer (score 2):

Copy the process id from `ps -e` command and then run the following:

```
ps x | grep <process-id>
```

Comment: Won't that fail if an application edits argv[0]? iirc sendmail does that.

Comment: Yes, it is a probability. None the less this comes handy almost every time.

Answer (score 0):

None of the methods (`ls`, `lsof` or `cat`) in the other answers work for me.
If I do:

```
$ nano test.txt
```

This is my winner,:

```
$ pgrep -f -l test
3074 nano test.txt
```

Or, in order to obtain only the PID to use it in programming:

```
$ pgrep -f test
3074
```

Tested on Kali Linux v1.0.6 (Debian based).
Compared to a simple `ls`, I must admit it is not a so portable solution, but at least it works.